# Как создать новый проект Django в терминале Ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, django

Установил джанго на убунту, подскажите, как выполнить команду в терминале на файл джанго-админ.ру, чтобы создать новый проект.

Comment: Если Вы только начинаете изучать **`Django`**, советую Вам почитать [**`документацию`**][1].


  [1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/#first-steps

Comment: Такие вопросы нужно искоренять!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два варианта установки - либо через репозитарии (правильный способ) или ручками, скачав с сайта и распаковав (хорош, если нужно иметь самые последние версии или несколько версий одновременно).

В первом случае просто в консоли нужно ввести django-admin (это точно так на fedora) либо django-admin.py (возможно есть дистрибутивы, где нужно так вводить).

Во втором случае нужно либо добавить путь к django-admin.py в переменную PATH, либо каждый раз вводить полный путь.

Answer (score 3):

sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/django/bin/django-admin.py /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py 
cd /home/user/ 
django-admin.py startproject myprj

и все. 
p.s: пути до файла могут отличатся. 
p.p.s: мог печататься в.буквам пишу с мобилы